# SyntaxError: no binding for nonlocal 'x' found

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции

Имеется код:

```
x = 1

def A():
    global x
    print(x + 1)
    def B():
        nonlocal x
        print(x + 2)
    B()
A()

def C():
    global x
    return x + 1
```

Выдает следующую ошибку:

```
  File "main.py", line 6
    nonlocal x
    ^
SyntaxError: no binding for nonlocal 'x' found
```

Вопрос: чем вызвана эта ошибка и как можно ее исправить?

**P.S.** Приведенная "программа" — это сильно упрощенный реальный код. Заранее предупреждаю: в программе необходима такая и именно такая архитектура. Дело в том, что в переменная `x` может быть огромного размера (1+ MB), а функция `B()` может вызываться миллионы раз, поэтому передавать `x` при вызывании функции `B()` нельзя — программа будет страшно виснуть.

Comment: поменяйте с `nonlocal` на `global` и всё будет работать как вы задумали

Comment: Вас интересует вопрос "почему?"

Comment: @Acinit С языка сняли. Как раз коммент писал) И зачем вообще nonlocal тогда нужно?

Comment: Странно, что при передачи в качестве аргумента получаются просадки. В норме такого не должно происходить, если у вfc при этом нигде не выполняется копирование переменной. Какой тип имеет ваша переменная x? Я бы посоветовал разбираться с этим, а не городить костыли с global.

Comment: @Xander, тип переменной x — словарь {int: int}. В нем до миллиона членов. Между вызовами функции B() словарь изменяется.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Существует в Python такое понятие как **области видимости**. Принципы его работы заложены в [LEGB Rule](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-rules-for-local-and-global-variables-in-python) официальной документации.

Начнём с простого. **Local**.

Данная зона видимости локальна относительно представления (функции или класса). Например

```
def example_function():
    local_variable = 10
    print("Локальная переменная:", local_variable)

example_function()
print(local_variable) #данное вызовет ошибку, так как local_variable не существует.
```

Вывод в терминале:

```
Локальная переменная: 10
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
NameError: name 'local_variable' is not defined
```

---

**Global**

Если переменная объявлена вне функций сама по себе существующая, то она является глобальной. Чтобы использовать её контекст, нужно использовать `global`. Вот пример, где мы переназначаем глобальную переменную.

```
global_variable = 10

def example_function():
    global global_variable
    global_variable = 20
    print("Глобальная переменная внутри функции:", global_variable)

print("Глобальная переменная перед вызовом функции:", global_variable)
example_function()
print("Глобальная переменная после вызова функции:", global_variable)
```

---

**nonlocal**

Если нам необходимо запросить контекст переменной у родительского представления вложенной функцией, то мы пользуемся `nonlocal`. Например создадим родительскую функцию и вложим в неё другую функцию, вызовем переменную из родительской функции и изменим её, прибавив 10. А затем попробуем вызвать её глобально.

```
def outer_function():
    outer_variable = 10

    print("Внешняя переменная до изменений:", outer_variable)

    def inner_function():
        nonlocal outer_variable
        outer_variable = outer_variable + 10
        print("Нелокальная переменная:", outer_variable)

    inner_function()
    
    print("Внешняя переменная после изменений:", outer_variable)

outer_function()
print(outer_variable)
```

Вывод терминала:

```
Внешняя переменная до изменений: 10
Нелокальная переменная: 20
Внешняя переменная после изменений: 20
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
NameError: name 'outer_variable' is not defined
```

---

**Вывод**

В вашем случае работа происходит с **глобальной переменной `x`**, а следовательно надо воспользоваться директивой получения глобальной переменной `global`:

```
x = 1

def A():
    global x
    print(x + 1)
    def B():
        global x
        print(x + 2)
    B()
A()
```

Answer (score 3):

`nonlocal` выдаёт ошибку, так как сама инструкция ищет нелокальные переменные, **исключая глобальные**.
Правильный пример:

```py
def A():
    x = 1
    def B():
        nonlocal x
        print(x)
    B()
A()
```

В вашем же случае `x` является глобальной переменной, что не подходит под определение инструкции.

Comment: Но тогда функция С() , будет выводить ошибку. Вы ее выкинули из примера, а она немаловажна.